# Boltzmann Distribution - Why maximum number of microstates?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I've recently started to learn statistical mechanics and I've run into Boltzmann Distribution. I wanted to see how it is derived and found some articles on web, but no one of them explain why the idea is to maximize the number of microscopic states that satisfy a given macro-state. This is my question: what is the explication, or the intuition behind this idea? Why should we maximize that function?

Comment: Most of the girls in Sweden are blond. You make up a story to your friend of how you made out with a beautiful Swedish girl. What hair colour should you tell him the girl had, if you want to make it realistic?

Comment: Ok. And how it is related to my problem? Beaucase I do not know anything but the total energy is fixed and also the number of particles. I do not know that "most of the .." or these kind of facts.

Comment: You have a bunch of different energy levels (hair colours), and for each level $E$, there are a number of states (girls) with that energy. [The premise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics#Fundamental_postulate) is that if you have to guess which energy is most realistic, you should choose the one with the most representatives. (Then, for the derivation of the Boltzmann distribution, you want to observe that probability for joint systems is multiplicative in $\mathbb R$, the energy fraction $E/T$ is additive in $\mathbb R$, and $\exp$ is the homomorphism from $\cdot$ to $+$.)

Comment: does this discussion have to be so genderized? can't you think of another analogy?

Comment: @innisfree: None that I would have fun writing down. We count states and more states for an energy means that energy is more likely. Hence, if we want to cut it down to the macroscopic realization, the extremal one will be the most relevant. Imho the math speaks for itself, but he asked for further intuition regarding where the quest for the maximum comes in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in probability theory.

Roughly, the probability of an event or macro state $A$ to happen is the number of instances $\Omega(A)$ in which it is fulfilled divided by the total number of possible instances or micro states $\Omega$ i.e.

$p(A) = \frac{\Omega(A)}{\Omega}$.

So the reason why you want to maximize $\Omega(A)$ is because you seek the macro-state that is more likely to be observed.

In the thermodyanmic limit, the most probable macro state is often overwhelmly more probable than any other macro state and it is basically the only one to be observed.

Comment: but what motivates the assumption that all microstates are equally probable?

Comment: @innisfree: I linked to that postulate in the comment you criticized, and it discusses motivations.

Comment: As far as equilibrium statistical mechanics is concerned, the equiprobability of micro states is mostly a postulate as NikolajK reported. It can be justified in some cases by looking at the ergodicity of the system or by applying statistical inference criteria (also called Bayesian inference).